# Big space between subsection, text and graphics

Tags: spacing, graphics, sectioning

I have a problem with space between subsection, text and image. I have code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Some title}
Some text in section

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{image1.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Diagram klas aplikacji serwera}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{image2.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{Diagram klas aplikacji klienta}
\end{center}

\subsection{Some title 2}
Some text...
\end{document}
```

And my document looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write `\raggedbottom` into the preamble.

Comment: `\raggedbottom` is on by default in `article`, if `twoside` is not used.

Comment: `\raggedbottom` works! Thank you very much.